# Polymer bind value through core element

Tags: polymer

I have a problem with passing the `category` variable inside the `<template>` tag wrapped by the `core-list`.

I tried [different binding approaches](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html), but no luck. `{{category}}` corretcly appears outside the 2nd template tag.

```
<polymer-element name="library-list" attributes="category">
<template>
    <style>
    ...
    </style>

    <service-library id="library" items="{{items}}"></service-library>

    <core-list id="list" data="{{items}}" on-core-select="{{onClick}}">
        <template>
            <div class="item {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}" hidden?="{{category == type}}">
                <div class="message">
                    <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </core-list>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try the injection approach.

```
 <core-list data="{{data}}">
    <template>
      <div class="item {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">
          <span>{{foo}}-<b>{{category}}</b></span>
      </div>
    </template>
  </core-list>
...
data.push({
    foo: 999,
    category:this.category,
    ...});
```

jsbin demo http://jsbin.com/mokok

Comment: `{{data}}` is already occupied with an ajax request I need to pass data besides it.

Comment: my two cents. a hidden element to inject the category into the data object. http://jsbin.com/loyoyo/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good solution, so I filtered the data instead that the `core-list` displays.